# How do i get difference when two servers have same IP during Migration?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am moving from Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2016 where my server team told both servers will have the same IP address. How does my code know if the current server is 2008 or 2016 and how can I persist the server value (2008 or 2016) in my code?

Comment: you should NEVER have the the same IP address on the same segment at ANY TIME. [*frown*] assign a _temporary_ address [or let DHCP do it].

Comment: What Lee said. But to answer your question, a PowerShell script running on a Windows computer can determine the OS version via WMI, e.g. `(gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem).Caption`.